# The Thumbnailator library converts image to cmyk

Tags: java, image, rgb

I'm reading an image at full size with correct orientation with the Thumbnailator library which honors EXIF orientation flags.

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(filepath) );
BufferedImage image = Thumbnails.of(is).scale(1).asBufferedImage();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(filepath));
```

But after converting the colorls are vrong so I checked the color model with XnView and it shows jpeg cmyk.

The original image was rgb. So why colors are wrong after using Thumbnailator library?

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem. I resolved the issue by saving it as PNG. Thumbnailator has got several issues and like the version (0.x.x) suggests there is no stable version out yet.

You can find the detailed solution at this [link](http://abhishekkothari.in/web-development/handling-exif-data-html-webpages/)